# How to extend ActionBarActivity and ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, multiple-inheritance

I need use two inheritance in one activity i.e.`ActionBarActivity` and `ListActivity`. How can i do?

Note: I have appcompat_v7 library

Here is my some snippet of code :

```
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar =  getSupportActionBar(); 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("test");
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you can't ... use ListFragment inside ActionBarActivity ...

Comment: i know , i can't but there must be a way

Comment: yes, there are few ways: 1. use ListFragment(right way) or 2. copy source code of ListActivity and make it extends ActionBarActivity instead Activity then use this class instead ListActivity(very bad way) 3. wait, thereis no other way ... i really don't get why don't you wana use ListFragment, the interface for accessing the listview is almost the same... anyway me: *you can't*, you: *i know , i can't but there must be a way* hehe ... logic fail ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot extend two objects simultaneously. [Directly from Oracle's inheritance tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object.